# JSON parsing using jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON which is like this-

```
var json = { 
    "http://data.abc.net/uml/extensions#0001" : { 
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label" : [ { 
            "type" : "literal" ,
            "location" : "ASIA" ,
            "datatype" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
        }]
    }
    ,
    "http://data.abc.net/uml/extensions#0002" : { 
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label" : [ { 
            "type" : "literal" ,
            "location" : "EUROPE" ,
            "datatype" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
        }]
    }
}
```

I am trying to parse this using JQUERY and want to store the values ASIA and EUROPE in an array called allREgions. I have written a code like this-

```
var allRegions = [];
var output = $.parseJSON(json);
var list = output.data;

$.each(list,function(index, val){
    allRegions.push(val.location);
});
```

But this is not working. What is going wrong in here?

Comment: Tried to format as best I could :D

Comment: not a valid json...! `}],` you have a trailing comma where asia is located.

Comment: Check your JSON validity at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I guess now the JSON is valid Thanks Kunj, checked it with the site, can you some one please help with the Parsing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you dont need to use $.parseJSON, just do:

```
var allRegions = [];
$.each(json, function(idx, val) {
    $.each(val, function(idxSec, valSec) {
        allRegions.push(valSec[0].location);
    });
});
console.log(allRegions);
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7twf6/)

Comment: Hi Sudhir, the jsFiddle is not working can you please check it mate?

Comment: @somsuvra seems to be fine:: 
["ASIA", "EUROPE"] is the output, isnt that what was needed to be done..? check browser's console pls

Comment: I did not downvite this mate, I just accepted this, in fact I cant downvote or upvote yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you do not have JSON. You have a JavaScript object literal. You don't need to parse it (because parsing JSON converts JSON into an object), and trying to do so will first convert it to a string (which wouldn't be valid JSON).

Replace `var output = $.parseJSON(json);` with `var output = json;`.

Your second problem is that you don't have a `data` property in the object. Your properties are `http://data.abc.net/cib/cia/uml/extensions#0001` and `http://data.abc.net/cib/cia/uml/extensions#0002`

Replace `var list = output.data;` with `var list = output`.

You can skip both those steps and just apply the data to the right thing in the first place.

Your third problem is that when you loop over them, your values are objects with one property (`http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label`) so you can't access `location`.

To get to that you have to read the value of that property, then get the first index of the array that its value is, and then access the location of *that*.

```
var data = {
    "http://data.abc.net/cib/cia/uml/extensions#0001": {
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label": [
            {
                "type": "literal",
                "location": "ASIA",
                "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
            }
        ]
    },
    "http://data.abc.net/cib/cia/uml/extensions#0002": {
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label": [
            {
                "type": "literal",
                "location": "EUROPE",
                "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
            }
        ]
    }
}

  var allRegions = [];

  $.each(data,function(index, val){
    allRegions.push(val['http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label'][0].location);
  });
```

Comment: Quentin, why are you using this - val['http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label'][0] Asking this as 'location' is the second member in the array.

Comment: @somsuvra — There are two arrays in `data`, but both of them have only one member. `http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label` is the name of the only property in each of the two objects that are the values of the two properties of `data` itself. JavaScript objects do not have order, so `location` cannot be "second".

Comment: I've reformatted the JS to make it clearer where the arrays and objects are. Pay close attention to the difference between `{}` and `[]`.